# Can nop commerce suppoert multible sellers

Tags: c#, .net, nopcommerce

I'm new to nop commerce and I'm using version 4.0 (.Net core2), I've a project and I'm considering using nop commerce for it but I want to know weather nop commerce supports multiple sellers where every seller has his/her own account/stores/products/reports or not??
and if not is there an alternative open source .NET product that does???
thanks

Comment: https://www.nopcommerce.com/blog/83-top-multi-store-and-multi-vendor-features-in-nopcommerce.aspx

Comment: thanks for your support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes Nopcommerce do support multiple sellers with its own account and its personal store.